# Running sequential operations in Webflux

Tags: mono, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have 2 services that I want to call back to back in a sequential fashion. Neither of them produces any data. What would be the best way to chain them in a webflux pipeline.

I want to call subscribe on the last service call to trigger the whole flow. Something like:

```
serviceA.methodX()
.then()
serviceB.methodY().subscribe()
```

Comment: what have you tried before posting?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I figured as an alternative:

```
Mono.just(Boolean.TRUE)
.flatMap( success -> { serviceA.methodX(); return true; } )
.flatMap( success -> { serviceB.methodY(); return true; } )
.subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Mono<OfSomeThing> executeFirst = ... ;

Mono<OfSomeThing> onceFirstIsCompletedExcecuteSecond = ... ;

Mono<OfSomeThing> plan = executeFirst.then(onceFirstIsCompletedExcecuteSecond);

plan.block();
```